# Looping and analyzing all files in directory and creating new subdirectories?

Tags: vba, excel

I have used the **`dir`** function to loop and analyze files before, but I'd like to add something else- creating two subdirectories in the working directory where output files are stored.

The first file in the directory gets analyzed and each of the outputs are stored in the newly created subdirectories. However, once the loop starts over, **`dir()`** returns: `""` and kicks me out of the loop.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub ProcessHCTFiles()
Dim Filename, Pathname As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim WrkngDir

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\ForReports\"
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xls")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
        CRprts wb, Pathname
        wb.Activate
        WrkngDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It would be important to note that the macro file is stored in the parent directory of where the files to be analyzed are stored, i.e. this line:

```
 Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\ForReports\"
```

and

```
 Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xls")
```

Comment: I run your macro as it is (just making sure having proper folders and dummy files in them) with no problems. may be it's something you're doing in "CRprts". besides: you don't need "wb.Activate", you can just go "WrkngDir = wb.Path". Finally its seems you don't use "WrkngDir"

Comment: It looks like the issue I was having was indeed in CRprts. Thanks for the input. Thanks for the other tip as well- cleaned that up in the code. "WrkingDir" was used later on in the code. Thanks for the help!